# ¿Como mostrar un div oculto con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

He visto por Internet unos ejemplos pero no me han funcionado de la manera que requiero, y es que cuando yo le de clic a el `id` de un `href` que es el mismo de un `div` me muestre la tabla que esta oculta.

**CODIGO HTML**

```
  <a href="#" id="display_table_students"> DB STUDENTS</a>
<br>
    <div id="display_table_students" style="display: block;">
                                    <table id="table_student" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                                <th>Apellido</th>
                                                <th>Correo</th>
                                                <th>Editar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

**CODIGO JS**

```
$('#display_table_students').click(function(e)
    {

      $("#formNewStudent").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
      $("#formUpdatePassword").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
      $("#formNewStudent").fadeOut(100);
      $("#formUpdatePassword").fadeOut(100);
      $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
      $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

¿Que es lo que pasa? que tengo unos formularios con un pequeño efecto ej:

```
REGISTRAR ESTUDIANTES | ACTUALIZAR ESTUDIANTES |  DB STUDENTS <-(ESTOS SON LINKS)
```

Cada ves que oprimo un link se oculta uno y se muestra el otro con un formulario lo que deseo es cuando de click en el `LINK DB STUDENTS` se muestre la tabla a la cual le puse un `style= 'none'`ya que si le quito este atributo o estilo se me ve reflejada en todos los links.

En pocas palabras que unica y exclusivamente apenas de click en `DB STUDENTS` me aparezca la tabla oculta.

Espero me haya hecho entender y agradezco el interes.

Comment: porque usas `.delay(100)` si usas `.fadeIn(100)` el 100 es el `delay` del `fadeIn`

Comment: perdona mi  ignorancia @JuankGlezz eso afecta con mi problema?

Comment: no afecta, el delay es un retraso de la animación, el 100 de `fadeIn` es la duración de la animación, me confundí, disculpa

Comment: Ok, entonces tomo ese comentario o respuesta como algo no constructivo ¿cierto?

Comment: como comentario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuida de los `id` duplicados, en `html` no deberían existir duplicados por este problema.

```js
$('#display_table_students').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  $("#display_table_students").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
  $("#table_student").fadeIn(1000);
});

//ocultando el div con id display_table_students
$('#ocultar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  $("#display_table_students").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  $("#table_student").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="display_table_students"> DB STUDENTS</a>
<a href="#" id="ocultar"> ocultar</a>
<br>
<div id="display_table_students" style="display: block; border: 1px solid black;">
  <table id="table_student" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

El usar `id` y este esta duplicado tiende a ocultar el primero que encuentra en este caso el enlace.

Ahora resolviendo tu caso seria algo así usando `id` unicos:

```js
$('#display_table_students').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#table_student").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
  $("#table_student2").fadeOut(100);
});

$('#display_table_students2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  $("#table_student").fadeOut(100);
  $("#table_student2").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="display_table_students"> DB STUDENTS</a>
<a href="#" id="display_table_students2"> DB STUDENTS2</a>
<br>
<div id="div_table_students" style="display: block; border: 1px solid black;">
  <table id="table_student" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table id="table_student2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre2</th>
        <th>Apellido2</th>
        <th>Correo2</th>
        <th>Editar2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No uses id duplicidados, los id significan identificadores, trata de que estos sean identificadores unicos, si tienes dos contenedores que son similares mejor usa clases